# DropDown menu has repeat issue on dropdown

Tags: html, css, menu, repeat

http://jsfiddle.net/Just1End/BTLXS/

If you look at the link above you will see that the drop down is weird. The first item of every drop down is always highlighted with an image.... And when you hover over the items (in the dropdown) they are given the image. Can you help me figure out how I can make it so that the dropdown peice remains red color and changes to a lighter red on hover. I also dont want the image to appear on the first item. Its weird. This is also my first attempt at a drop down menu and I would really like help. Thanks

CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>    </script>
<style>
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: url(http://minecraft-serverlist.org/e-scape/bg.png) repeat-x top left;
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}
 #cssmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
  #cssmenu li ul {
     position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

#cssmenu li ul li {
    display: block;
}

 #cssmenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
 }
#cssmenu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #A79787;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
 }
#cssmenu li a:hover,
#cssmenu .active {
  color: #fff;
  background: url(http://minecraft-serverlist.org/e-scape/bg.png) repeat-x top left;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 #cssmenu .active a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  background-color: #B11718;
}
#cssmenu li a:hover,
#cssmenu li.active {
  background-color: #DE3330;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='team'><span>Team</span></a>
       <ul>
            <li><a href='team'>Team</a></li>
            <li><a href='team'>Team2</a></li>
            <li><a href='team'>Team3</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='sponsors'><span>Sponsors</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='first'><span>First</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='contact-us'><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='handouts'><span>Handouts</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will need to add background: red; or whatever color you would like to your #cssmenu li ul declaration...currently you are setting a background image on all UL's so your first sub-ul is receiving that as well (cascading). Then you will just need to add whatever light red (i am using orange as the example) you would like as the hover effect to an li ul li a declaration so that it receives the correct styling.

```
#cssmenu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: red;
}

#cssmenu li ul li a:hover {
    background: orange;
}
```

Comment: @user2759665 The sub-ul is right there in my code example.  I'm not sure what you mean by "I'm not sure which and how I should code the sub ul"...all I did was take your current declaration and add background:red;

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this class: `#cssmenu ul`

according to this class you set background to all `ul`s after `#cssmenu`, so the drop-down menu have a background. for fix this issue you need to add another class like this:

```
#cssmenu ul li ul{
    background:#B11718;
}
```

here is a [**fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/vByeE/1/)